# Why is $\frac {d}{dx} (x^2) = 2x$ not $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, slope

I am new at calculus and so I am studying derivatives now. We know that, $$\frac {d}{dx} (x^2) = 2x$$

I know the proof of it by the first rule derivatives. But still, my question is why. It is simply calculating the slope when $y = x^2$ with respect to $x$. Here is the graph of $y = x^2$

[image]

In this graph it is really clear that when $x = 3$, $y = 9$

If a slope is defined as $\tan \theta$ which is equal to $y\over x$ in a graph.

Then, why $\frac {d}{dx} (x^2) ≠ x$ when $y = x^2$ as the slope $\frac {x^2}{x} = x$?

Comment: The slope of the line isn't equal to $\frac {y}{x}$ if the line doesn't pass through $(0,0)$. The formula of slope being "tan $\theta$" applies when you're joining a point to the origin, or you know two points on a line. This is the tangent line, so all you know is that it passes through $(x,y)$. How does that tell you its slope?

Comment: Why can't we define the slope when the line passing through $(0, 0)$ ?

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas We can *mention* it, but it is not *that* slope, it is the *tangent's* slope that we use to define the derivative. On the curve, compare the chord through $(0,0)$ and $(3,9)$ with the *tangent* at $(3,9)$. The slope of the latter is obviously bigger (more steep) than of the former, and when you calculate it, it comes out as exactly $2x=2\cdot 3$ rather than $3$.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking , but basically : you have a point $(x,y)$ at which you want to find the slope of the tangent line. Now, all you know about the tangent line is that it passes through $(x,y)$. How can you find the slope of a line by knowing just one point that it passes through? The formula that the slope of a line is $\tan \theta$ requires more information about the line than just one point.

Comment: In fact you can tell from the correct analysis that the tangent at $(x,x^2)$ cuts the $x-$axis at $(\frac x2, 0)$ because the tangent line is twice as steep as the chord from the origin.

Comment: To find the slope of the tangent, take the point $(x, x^2)$ and a very close point $(x+h, (x+h)^2)$ (small $|h|$) and calculate the slope of the chord between those two points. It comes out as $\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{(x+h)-x}=\frac{2xh+h^2}{h}=2x+h$. "Obviously" when $|h|$ is then made smaller and smaller (the chord closer and closer to the real tangent), this is approaching $2x$. ("Obviously" in quotes because I want to gloss over the precise definitions of what "approaching" means in this context, i.e. I want to gloss over the definition of the **limit**.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop I knew this before but I didn't understand why is the slope equals to  $2x$ if the slope line was passing through the origin. But now my doubt is clear. Thank you all for giving time to my question.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a duplicate

Comment: An easier example to see that this does not work : Consider the line $f(x)=x+1$ , obviously having slope $1$. If you take some point $(u/u+1)$ , the slope would be according to your definition $\frac{u+1}{u}$ , so dependent on $u$ instead of being always $1$.

Comment: What is the point of putting more than 2 downvote on a newbie question..? Jeez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Your $\frac{x^2}{x}$ is not the slope of the graph at $x$. It is the slope of the line from the origin to the point $(x,x^2)$ on the graph.

[Interactive plot.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lrkblrvkjd)

Comment: Oh so it is! Thank you for this graph to make it the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Slope at point $(x_0, y_0)$ is defined as $\tan\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle subtended by the tangent to the curve at point $(x_0, y_0)$ from the x-axis.

Slope $= \frac{dy}{dx}|_{(x_0, y_0)}  \ne \frac{y_0}{x_0}$.

$\frac{y_0}{x_0}$ gives the slope of the chord joining origin $(0, 0)$ and point $(x_0, y_0)$.